# How does django request is handled in views?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

This is the piece of code i want to know how it handles both get and post request.I get confused most of the time how to get a better understanding of this so that i can write more better back-end codes .

```
    def post_create(request):
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        form=PostForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance =form.save(commit=False)
            #print form.cleaned_data.get("title")
            instance.user=request.user
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
        context={
            "form":form,}
        return render(request,"post_form.html",context)
    else:
        raise Http404
```

This piece of code for handling the request to create Post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This view doesn't make any distinctions between various request methods such as GET or POST. If it did, you would see something like this:

```
def post_create(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # your code
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        # your code
```

Comment: So if i am not wrong if their is no staff or superuser it wont handle any request and it will raise 404 error ?

Comment: It won't raise the error, it just won't return any response. Unless you write an else.